# Binding a grid with two datasources in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I'm having a problem with how I should bind my datagrid in the best way.

The problem is that i would like to use two itemSources. 
I have a list with alot of incidents, each incident holds a list of buggs. 
What I would like to do is bind half a gridview row with some of the fields from the incident, and half of the grid with the corresponding bugs that the incident holds.

How would I be able to do this in the best way?

I have access to the componentOne datagrid, but if the normal grid works it's all good.

But I do would like to have a sorting ability.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to make sure that you don't have `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`.

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">    
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="ItemSource1Property1Name" 
                Width="SizeToHeader"
                Binding="{Binding ItemSource1.Property1}" 
                FontSize="20" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="ItemSource1Property2Name" 
                Width="SizeToHeader"
                Binding="{Binding ItemSource1.Property2}" 
                FontSize="20" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="ItemSource2Property1Name" 
                Width="SizeToCells"
                Binding="{Binding ItemSource2.Property1}" 
                FontSize="20" />
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        .
        .
        .
        Rest of Code
        .
        .
        .
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**

If you choose to use an wrapper for your item source then you will have something like this in your code:

```
public class ItemWrapper
{
    ObservableCollection<ItemSource1Type> ItemSource1 {get;set;}
    ObservableCollection<ItemSource2Type> ItemSource2 {get;set;}
}
```

And then in your view model or code behind (where ever you want to set the properties you want to bind to):

```
public class ViewModel //This may just end up being your code behind depending on how you have your entire SL project set up.
{
    ItemWrapper ItemWrapper { get; set; } //set the two properties either in the constructor or in whatever code initializes ViewModel.
}
```

In your xaml:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ItemSource="{Binding ItemWrapper}"
              DataContext="{Binding}">    
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="ItemSource1Property1Name" 
                Width="SizeToHeader"
                Binding="{Binding ItemSource1.Property1}" 
                FontSize="20" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, but how would this ItemSourceWrapper look like, please some code behind so I can see how I should add my two sources into the wrapper.. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually had meant to take that out. I dont think you need to have an ItemSource if you are not autogenerating the columns. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Another option though would be to make a simple wrapper that has two properties set to each type of your two item sources. You can then set the item source to that wrapper and reference each Item source in the wrapper using the same dot notation

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Kavet's idea but his solution is far away then the reality.
According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.95).aspx

ItemSourse must have  IEnumerable interface implemented.

that mean  your ItemWrapper  will not work at all.

Have you tried to run this?