# How to bind to a property of a collection for a data grid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I was trying to write a sample code to test out the question asked @ [Binding a grid with two datasources in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224747/binding-a-grid-with-two-datasources-in-silverlight)

I have a XAML as

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding WrapperClass}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding People.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My view model code

```
private ItemWrapper _wrapperClass;
    public ItemWrapper WrapperClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (_wrapperClass == null)
                _wrapperClass = new ItemWrapper();
            return _wrapperClass;
        }
    }
```

The item wrapper and person class definition

```
public class ItemWrapper
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return _people;
        }
    }        

    public ItemWrapper()
    {
        _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        _people.Add(new Person { ID = 1, Name = "Name1", JobTitle = 1 });
        _people.Add(new Person { ID = 2, Name = "Name2", JobTitle = 2 });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the program if binding property works, I was expecting names to show in the grid but it does not. It just shows the header. Am I missing anything here?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding WrapperClass.People}">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Yes that will work but that is not what I am trying to solve. What I am trying to solve is to have two different data sources where all columns are from People while there will be a list box, its data source will be another property of Wrapper class.

Comment: I have just answered "Am I missing anything here?",...........   in short  you need 1:1 mapping between your collection(Data source) and control( datagrid).  Another hint I can give you which is a trick in Binding itself. you can use `{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, Source={Relative/StaticResource  .....}}`,  But still you need seperate collection at **Item** level as you can not bind Item to Collection

Comment: Thanks and I agree about the model of binding. What I am after is the solution provided in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224747/binding-a-grid-with-two-datasources-in-silverlight (as I mentioned in the first of the question)