# How to use two datacontexts in binding expression?

Tags: silverlight

Here is the situation, data grid is bound to a list of dtos, and during the edit, comboboxes need to display a list of active users, plus the one that is on the dto being bound for the row. Since list of all available users exists on the model and need to do indexing per row of data grid. For that I need to reference two data contexts. How to do that?

Here is xaml

```
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="UW" Width="150">
                                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <c:ComboBox Width="145" Height="25" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cc}, Path=AvailableUnderwritersPerProposal[BidVersionId]}" 
                                    SelectedValueProper="{Binding Path=UnderwriterId, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Source={StaticResource cc}, Path=DataContext.HasPermissionsToEditUnderwriter}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This line here 
AvailableUnderwritersPerProposal[BidVersionId] is the problem, since BidVersionId is on the datacontext of the datagrid, and AvailableUnderwritersPerProposal is one level up.

Comment: Have a look at the answer in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224747/binding-a-grid-with-two-datasources-in-silverlight

Answer (score 1):

just thought,

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cc}, Path=AvailableUnderwritersPerProposal[{Binding BidVersionId}]}"
```

Finger crossed!!

Dipak.